# gpupdate failing when using Samba 4 AD DC

Tags: active-directory, samba, domain-controller

I have a Samba 4 AD domain running with 2 DCs on Centos 6.5, with a named DNS backend.

I have multiple Windows 7 machines joined to this domain, which is fine.

However, I can't get GPOs to apply.

When running gpupdate, I get the following output

The processing of Group Policy failed. Windows attempted to read the file \\sysvol\\Policies{31B2F340-016D-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9}\gpt.ini

Obviously, you don't normally see what it's trying to connect to when it's successful, but I would have thought the first place  shows up, I should be seeing

So, what governs what data gets put in between those angle brackets?

If it is just supposed to be the domain, then what else could be going wrong?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: "So, what governs what data gets put in between those angle brackets?" The data in the curly brackets IS correct and is the GUID a group policy object.

Comment: ...and those are *curly*, not angle.

Answer (score 0):

> So, what governs what data gets put in between those angle brackets?

That is the full path to the GPO. That GUID is not a placeholder, it is the GUID of he GPO and is used on the file system.

Comment: I actually did have 2 pieces of data with angles brackets in, but they somehow got stripped out. The url starts with \\mydomain.com\sysvol, not \\myhost.mydomain.com\sysvol, and I just wondered if this was correct

Comment: Yes. It is correct.